Ignore TypeScript errors under all circumstances
How can I always ignore a TypeScript error without getting an error if the actual error does not occur?
Background is this snippet:
  const render = await (async () => {
    if (viteDevServer) {
      return (await viteDevServer.ssrLoadModule('./src/entryServer.ts')).render
    }

    // @ts-expect-error File may not be compiled in development
    return (await import('./dist/server/entry/entryServer.js')).render
  })()

With @ts-expect-error an error occurs if the file exists.
Without @ts-expect-error an error occurs if the file does not exist.

Downvoters have not understood, that there is no other way...

use // @ts-ignore instead.
 const render = await (async () => {
  if (viteDevServer) {
    return (await viteDevServer.ssrLoadModule('./src/entryServer.ts')).render
  }

  // @ts-ignore
  return (await import('./dist/server/entry/entryServer.js')).render
})()

but please keep in mind that you should do it sparingly (not at all in best case) since it can hide real issues in your code.

Yes, you're right. @ts-expect-error will fail if there is no error, @ts-ignore will not! I didn't notice this because it's underlined like an error in the IDE. But that's just an ESLint warning.
